# extracting soccer player informations from dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I tried to extract the following informations (soccerplayer name, team, team number, number of matches, number of goals) about soccer players from dbpedia using this query:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select distinct ?soccerplayer ?team ?number ?caps ?goals Where
{
?soccerplayer a dbo:SoccerPlayer ;
dbo:team ?team;
dbo:number ?number;
dbo:numberOfMatches ?caps;
dbo:numberOfGoals ?goals.
}
ORDER BY ?soccerplayer
```

Comment: ok, and you have the properties in your query from where? I mean, how did you find those properties? And did you check the data of a soccer player in DBpedia? just opening any player in the browser? For example click on http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lionel_Messi - what do you see? Correct, data is attached to careerstation, i.e. an intermediate object. get those and get data from each.

Comment: something like this: `PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select ?soccerplayer ?team ?number ?caps ?goals Where
{
?soccerplayer a dbo:SoccerPlayer ;
dbo:careerStation ?cs .
?cs dbo:team ?team .
?cs dbo:numberOfMatches ?caps .
?cs dbo:numberOfGoals ?goals .
OPTIONAL {?cs dbo:number ?number}

}
ORDER BY ?soccerplayer` - just in case, you should think about putting properties into OPTIONAL to allow for absence of e.g. goals. And I doubt there is data for team number.